# Where Does MySQL Save Error Logs on Windows?

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue using MySQL via Python `mysql.connector` library.

The error is very vague, it is:

`2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

There is no further information from the library on the stack, this seems to be all I've got. **I have looked at other StackOverflow questions and answers on this error, and the common reasons I've seen for this error do not match my case.** I am not trying to run long queries or SELECT huge datasets. I am running fairly small queries that only INSERT data.

I have tried my best looking through the logs in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data` and I also ran mysqld.exe with the `--log-warnings=2` argument and checked the logs it produced. Nothing.

I am looking to hopefully review some log file while can provide me with further details on why this might be happening. I am using MySQL on Windows Server 2019 Standard. Where could I find such a file, or any further details on the error?

Comment: You may enable General Log on MySQL and investigate it, you may investigate Error Log and Slow Query Log. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html

Answer (score 0):

It's located on this path: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data

and search for these files: ComputerName.log for general log and ComputerName.err for error log